# Can't able to set custom price when product has custom option

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options

I am set custom price for all product and its like a charm but when product as contain custom option is not update my custom price i don't know what is problem with my code.

Comment: please share code?

Answer (score 1):

For event you need to define similar to this code in config.xml file of your extension.

```
<frontend>
  <events>
    <add_to_cart_after>
                <observers>
                    <add_to_cart_after>
                        <class>[Your Obeserver Path]</class>
                        <method>[Your Observer Method Name]</method>
                    </add_to_cart_after>
                </observers>
            </add_to_cart_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

In observer you can do something like this :

```
$quoteData = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
   foreach ($quoteData as $quote_item) 
   {       
       $quote_item->setCustomPrice($price);
       $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
       $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
       $quote_item->save();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Custom options and Custom price cannot work at a time.
When any product has custom option, price is calculated based on options selection. So you need to modify your code according to this Magento structure.
Try below code when you write custom code:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
   foreach ($quote as $quoteItem) 
   {       
       $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price);
     $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
     $quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
     $quoteItem->save();
  }
```